# Run PHP Handler after running my handler Apache

Tags: php, apache

I have created a handler in Apache which is supposed to parse the URL entered. If the conditions defined by the handler are satisfied, the handler returns DECLINED AND the page requested is open. If not, the handler displays "Rejected". However, the problem I am facing is that when I am trying to display a PHP page, the PHP handler does not help execute the PHP code after my handler returns DECLINED. I have included the following lines in my httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule example5_module modules/mod_example5.so
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler example5-handler
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
</FilesMatch>
```

Here, example5_module is the module I wrote and example5-handler is my handler. The handler works completely fine and does its job of parsing the URL but on success it shows a blank page instead of executing the PHP code. I have also checked that PHP is working properly if I remove my handler. Please help me make my handler and the PHP handler work together.